# Switching coroutine context after withContext

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Assume we have coroutine context `io` for blocking operations and coroutine context `async` for non-blocking operations like coroutine execution.
How to implement following efficiently?

```kotlin
/**
 * Eval [f] on thread pool defined by [on], then continue execution on [continueOn] context
 */
suspend fun <A> eval<A>(f: () -> A, on: CoroutineContext, continueOn: CoroutineContext): A

eval({ readFileBlocking() }, io, async)
```

`eval` can be called from any context including `Unconfined`. `withContext(continueOn) { withContext(on) { f() }}` works but inefficient - it forces up to 4 thread pool switch while optimum is 2 (from input context to blocking pool, then to resulting context)

Q&A

- Why not just `withContext(IO){ ... }`?

  In case of unconfined context execution will continue on IO thread which is the behavior I want to avoid
- Why not `withContext(IO){ ... } ; withContext(async){ ... }`?

  If we put that inside a function, it has the same problem -
  unconfined context will continue execution on IO thread. If we
  don't, I don't like the idea of writing `withContext(async)` everywhere just because there was call to IO context somewhere.

Comment: What exactly is your use case here? Also, which code needs to be executed on `async` context?

Comment: I want to execute blocking code on separate thread pool. Also I want that pool to be used for blocking code only.

Comment: Ok but what is wrong with just using `withContext(IO)` when you need to? Why do you need this kind of `eval()` function with 2 contexts?

Comment: I think the OP's point is that if we need to do something like this: `withContext(on) { ... }; withContext(continueOn) { ... }` then between `on` and `continueOn` we need to switch to outer context which makes no sense. And this is really wasteful. I think OP is incorrect this is 4 switches vs 2 switches. It is 4 vs 3. I guess the compiler could try to optimize such cases and jump from `on` to `continueOn` directly, but it may not be that simple as `withContext()` is just a function.

Comment: @Joffrey in case of unconfined context after withContext(IO) execution will continue on IO thread

Comment: @SergeyAlaev I have yet to see a usage of the unconfined dispatcher in production code outside very local/specific areas. I usually don't even consider it. If people use it, they will need to take care of such dispatch issues themselves, but I doubt that a general helper function like shown here would be useful enough to justify its existence. The problem @broot mentions with 2 consecutive `withContext` is a different issue that is worth considering, but I don't think that's the same use case here.

Comment: Am I the only one who uses Flow together with reactivestreams client (async AWS S3) AND blocking stuff on the other side I wonder.